# void android.content.res.StringBlock.close() error using react-native-webrtc or jitsi

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, webrtc, jitsi

Hi, I am trying to include in my project using **react-native-webrtc** react native module but I am getting the following error. The main tip is that I got the same error when I used **jitsi**. Has anyone encountered this problem before? I've never seen a similar anywhere.

1. Application is receiving build success




2. App crashes when runtime




3. Unfortunately I have no more arguments for solving this problem.

```
     E/System: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.res.StringBlock.close()' on a null object reference
     at android.content.res.ApkAssets.close(ApkAssets.java:201)
     at android.content.res.ApkAssets.finalize(ApkAssets.java:191)
     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:289)
     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:276)
     at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:137)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
```

Comment: Hi,

Have the same issue after upgrading rn from 0.61.5 to 0.64.2 and code push from 6 to 7 

any ideas?